# Why is Android App crashing on startActivity?

Tags: android, debugging, android-intent, start-activity

So I have a very simply main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void setDecks(View view){
    EditText editTextCardNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String CardNumString = editTextCardNum.getText().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Cards.class);
    intent.putExtra("deckNumber", CardNumString);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Where I want the user to enter a number into the editText, which at the press of a button will be passed to a new activity. This always causes the app to crash though.

I tried commenting out things to see where it goes wrong, and it always fails at

```
startActivity(intent)
```

If that line is commented out, everything else works fine. The code for the new activity looks like

```
public int totalCards = 0;
public int unknownCards = 0;
public int deckNumber = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cards);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String stringOfDecks = intent.getStringExtra("deck Number");
    int numberOfDecks = Integer.parseInt(stringOfDecks);


    totalCards = numberOfDecks * 52;
    deckNumber = numberOfDecks;
    unknownCards = totalCards;
    //updateChance();


    TextView summary = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView14);
    summary.setText(Integer.toString(unknownCards));
 }
```

Previously, I had tried to pass the number through intent as an int instead of a String, and then my app would not stop and crash, but it turned out I was doing it improperly as

```
int numberOfDecks = intent.getIntExtra("key", 0)
```

was simply assigning that value to be 0?

EDIT

I just realized that part of the problem might have been when I was trying to change my layout from tablerow to constraint. Here is my activity_cards.xml file, did I accidentally delete a necessary line?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.jaimevandeveer.cardcounter.Cards">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="incrementA"
    android:text="A"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="2"
    android:onClick="increment2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonA" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="3"
    android:onClick="increment3"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="4"
    android:onClick="increment4"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="6"
    android:onClick="increment6"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="5"
    android:onClick="increment5"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="7"
    android:onClick="increment7"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/buttonA"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/buttonA" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button6" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="8"
    android:onClick="increment8"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textViewA"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="9"
    android:onClick="increment9"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="10"
    android:onClick="increment10"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button12" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonJ"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="J"
    android:onClick="incrementJ"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonQ"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Q"
    android:onClick="incrementQ"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonJ"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonK"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="K"
    android:onClick="incrementK"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonQ" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="58dp"
    android:layout_height="17dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button8" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button12" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewJ"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/buttonJ"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/buttonJ" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewQ"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/buttonQ"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/buttonQ" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewK"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="17dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/buttonK"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/buttonK"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonK"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What exception do you see on the logcat? can you post that?

Comment: post logcat thanks

Comment: Um, sorry I'm very new to this. What is the logcat? On android studio, it compiles fine and launches it on my device. Then when I hit the button, it says the App has stopped

Comment: Please refer https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html for logcat and understanding how to debug your program.

Comment: String stringOfDecks = intent.getStringExtra("deck Number"); <--- this should be deckNumber

Comment: your editText allow only digit or text also..? Please cofirm that not to send empty text, because you are converting into empty that place it will crash.

Comment: @JVandeve - please accept answer and vote up, if my solution has solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the second argument to `Intent` constructor is Activity class (CardsActivity, etc) and not a Java POJO (Cards).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, <ACTIVITY_CLASS_NAME>.class);
```

Replace `<ACTIVITY_CLASS_NAME>` with the activity class name where you want your app to transition on `startActivity`.

Make sure that you declare a `public static final String` constant for the key used to save data in and retrieve data from `Intent`.

```
public class MainActivity .... 
......
public static final String DECK_KEY = "deckNumber";
......
// when inserting data in intent
intent.putExtra(MainActivity.DECK_KEY, "value");

......
// when retrieving data from intent
String stringOfDecks = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.DECK_KEY);
```

Also make sure activity is declared under  tag under  tag in manifest file.

Comment: Hi, I created the Cards.java by right clicking app and making a new empty activity. Was I supposed to name it CardsActivity instead of just Cards for it to count as an activity class?

Comment: No, having Activity in name is just naming convention and makes easy to reader. If Cards.java is an activity then we would need more details on exception from logcat.

Comment: Can you also confirm that AndroidManifest xml has the Cards declared with activity tag?

Comment: I added the xml file. Where does the activity tag go? I think I might have deleted it

Comment: When you add activity by right clicking android studio adds that automatically.

Comment: I was messing around with the xml file and I'm worried I deleted it. Where would I add it back?

Comment: Refer this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html search for <activity>

Comment: if you are confused then just paste this below your MainActivity's `<activity>` tab `<activity android:name=".Cards"> </activity>`

Comment: FYI - your android maifest file be at <PROJECT-DIRECTORY>/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Given the name of you layout file

> activity_cards

I have to assume that your code needs the following revision from

> Intent intent = new Intent(this, Cards.class);

to

> Intent intent = new Intent(this, CardsActivity.class);

If my first assumption is wrong then I assume that you have built the activity and layout on your own, since they aren't following the same naming convention.  If that's the case, you may have forgotten to add the activity to your manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".Cards" />
```

Your's probably will end up looking like this:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Cards">
    </activity>
```

You also have a typo in your Cards onCreate method.

```
String stringOfDecks = intent.getStringExtra("deck Number");
```

should be:

```
String stringOfDecks = intent.getStringExtra("deckNumber");
```

Comment: My other activity  shows up as Cards.java and then has the layout as activity_cards, but my main activity is called MainActivity with layout as activity_main. Do I need to change the name of Cards.java? If i replace the code with new Intent(this, CardsActivity.class) it tells me that it cannot resolve the symbol